# How to access repository methods for an entity in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, repository, entity

I am stuck with a problem please help me with it. Here is the scenarario:

I have an entity "User" and corresponding repository "UserRepository", inside  my entity there are only getter and setter methods. All custom queries I have written to UserRepository. Now inside my UserController I am trying to access repository methods which I am not able to do so.
e.g. 
User entity:

```
class User
{
    ...

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        return $this->id=$id;
    }
    public function setProperty($property)
    {
        $this->property = $property;
    }


    public function getProperty()
    {
        return $this->property;
    }

    ....

    }
  ?>
```

UserRepository:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{


    public function findUsersListingById($id)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

       $query = $em->createQuery(
                    "SELECT U
                    FROM  UserEntityPathGoesHere
                    WHERE U.id IN (".implode(",", $id).")"
                );

        $users = $query->getResult();

        return $users;
    }

    public function sayHelloWorld(){

        echo ' Hello World';
    }

}
?>
```

UserController

```
class UserController
{
 ...


$users=$this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyUserEntityPath')
        ->findUsersListingById($ids);

    //now I have multiple users I want to iterate through each user for associating additional data with each user

     foreach($users as $user)
     {
        $temp = array();

        //I am able to access getId method which is  defined in User entity
        $temp['id'] = $user->getId();

        //however I am not able to  access method from UserRepository, I tried something like below which gives me error  call to undefined function sayHelloWorld
        $temp['status'] = $user->sayHelloWorld();

       ....

     }


}
```

....

How can I access repository methods for an entity? Is it possible ? If not then what are the alternatives for the solution?

Comment: I aware of the fact entity and repository don't need to be aware of each other, I am just trying to access repository methods

Comment: No.  You cannot access repository methods directly from your entity.  There is no direct link between the two.  The sayHelloWold method should be in the entity itself.  Or else you pass an entity to it:  $userRepository->sayHelloWorld($user);

Comment: @Cerad thanks for your thoughts, I am able call repository methods by passing entity itself, however I am wondering is this the appropriate way to do it? is there any other alternative like creating service that will have methods currently hold by UserRepository? I am thinking about creating service rather passing entity to each method in repositoy

Comment: I've added methods for iterating a user entity in either a controller or a template.

Comment: I did $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:User')->findById(array(1,2,3,4,5)); to fetch multiple users.a However to address my major concern, like  @cerad mentioned in his comment its not possible directly to access repository methods which I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Everything is possible **however** you should not access the entity's repository from the entity itself because of the separation of concerns.

See this [Stackoverflow answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187065/2155387).

Basically, the whole idea is that you want to have your application organized the following way.

In short:

#### Controller **>** Repository **>** Entities.

It should not go in the other direction otherwise it creates a mess.

If you want to go a bit further into the separation of concerns you could do the following.

#### Controller **>** Service **>** Repository **>** Entities

Alternative solutions:

- Create a [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) that access a service (which access a repository) or a repository.
- Create a method in your repository, call the method in your controller, map the data to IDs (keys of array are the IDs), pass the array to the template and then pull the data from the array using the entity IDs
- Create a method in your repository, call the method in your controller, inject the data into your entities and access the data through the entity in your template.

There are probably others but you would know better how your application is organized.

Comment: @Thomad I am doing this for an API where I will be throwing output in the form of json/xml, I guess I will opt for solution for which doesn't involve twig or templates

Comment: You should definitely use twig template (it's always useful) and it's meant for that (file extension can also be `*.json.twig`). Your best bet is to load the data in "parallel", inject it into your entities and access the data through your entity. It will be easier to debug and optimize later on.

Comment: sorry I didn't get "load the data in 'parallel' " can you please give me info?

Comment: as a different Repository method, one call for your entities, one call for the extra data

Answer (score 2):

If the bundle is `Acme/DemoBundle`, then one would expect at a minimum

#### User entity

```
namespace Acme/DemoBundle/Entity

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/UserRepository")
 */
class User 
{
...
}
```

#### User repository

```
namespace Acme/DemoBundle/Entity
    
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
...
}
```

It is also true that with an array of ids, one can also do the following in a controller:

```
...
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$users = $em->getRepository("AcmeDemoBundle:User")->findAllById($idArray);
...
```

To iterate through users in a controller, one can then use a `foreach` loop as in:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
//each user is an array
...
$id = $user['id'];
...
}
```

or in a template:

```
{% for user in users %}
...
{{ user.firstName }}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning findAllById method to get records with multiple ids, however is it possible to call repository method with entity e.g. $users[0]->someMethodFromUserRepo()  ?

Comment: You could do `$users = ...->findAllById($idArray); $firstUser = $users[0];`

Comment: yes I could do that, I mean I am able to iterate users, my main concern is accessing "repository" methods for each user. Is it possible to do this: $firstUser->someMethodFromUserRepo();

Comment: No. Add a repository method with a user as parameter. Inject the entity not the repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the postLoad event from doctrine and inject everything you want into the entity. The event listener looks like:

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;


use AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

/**
 * Class MyEntityListener
 */
class MyEntityListener
{

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        /** @var MyEntity $document */
        $document = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if(!($document instanceof MyEntity)){
            return;
        }
        $document->setEntityManager($eventArgs->getEntityManager());

    }
}
```

and service.yml:

```
services:
app.myentity.listener:
  class: AppBundle\EventListener\MyEntityListener
  tags:
    - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

Of cource your Entity needs the method setEntityManager and your're ready.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `UserRepository` as an `EntityRepository` for your user entity. In your `User` entity add this annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
```

See [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) for a more detailed description.

Comment: Yes I have already declared the UserRepository as an EntityRepository in my user entity file.