# Custom sorting/filtering in Doctrine 2 associations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, associations, dql

I often sort associated entities by a foreign attribute and I'm wondering how to best handle it and still be able to use collections of the main entity. Let's have this example:

```
Author { $name, Comment[] $comments}
Comment { $name, Category $category}
Category { $name, $position }
```

I want `$author->getComments()` sorted by the comment's category position. In terms of DQL:

```
SELECT com.* FROM comment com JOIN com.category cat ORDER BY cat.position
```

Truth be told, my sorting criteria are rather more complex, this is just to get us started.

I know about @OrderBy annotation for *ToMany associations but it won't help me because ordering by a joined table's attribute is not supported.

I also know I can use DQL to fetch the comments but I need to access them in many places and I'd prefer referencing `$author->getComments()` rather than calling `$commentRepository->findByAuthorSorted($author)`. I don't want having to remember to call my custom method to fetch the comments in the right way. I want it to be automatic.

I was considering somehow passing commentRepository to Author entity and use it in `getComments()` but I didn't figure out how to do it, plus it doesn't feel right to begin with.

I also thought about doing the sorting in PHP in `getComments()`. I don't think I can use `Criteria` + `$author->comments->matching()` because joined attributes don't seem to be supported. I'm fine with casting the collection to a read-only array but I hope there's a better, more Doctrine-way solution.

I don't want to work around the problem by adding `$categoryPosition` to each `Comment`.

I'd like to hear how you people handle this problem. I bet I'm not alone :-)

Comment: Would it be a clean solution to use `postLoad` event listener to inject CommentRepository into Author entity and then in `$author->getComments()` call `$this->commentRepository->findByAuthorSorted($this)`?

Comment: This question seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186970/symfony2-access-repository-functions-in-entity - I only found out now. I have to say though, I'm not happy with the answers. I'm supposed to either sort with PHP, or create an extra layer/class (AuthorService) that would provide access to all associations. So no more $author->getFoos(), $author->getBars() or $author->getComments(). It would be $authorService->getAuthorWithFoosBarsComments(). This method would fetch author and fill its associated collections. Seems way too impractical to me.